# Object Shoots On x-z Axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I actually have 2 issues. The first problem I have is that when I start my game all 4 cannons do their animation sequence for no reason, nothing happens. I'd like this to not happen. The second problem I have is the cannon ball that shoots out spawns on the floor and flies along the floor. Here is the code for the firing sequence:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Cannon : MonoBehaviour {
public AudioClip sound;
public GameObject prefab;
public GameObject ejectPoint;

void Start () {
    prefab = Resources.Load ("Cannon_Ball") as GameObject;
}


    public void Fire () {
        GameObject Cannon_Ball = Instantiate (prefab) as GameObject;
        Cannon_Ball.transform.position = transform.position + ejectPoint.transform.forward * 2;
        Rigidbody rd = Cannon_Ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        rd.velocity = ejectPoint.transform.forward * 130;
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(sound, transform.position, 1);
        GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ();
    }

}
```

Here is a GIF of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix 1: Uncheck 'Play Automatically' or find equal option in your Animator. I think after you start game, your Animator change his state from "Start" to "Shoot" because of bad conditions setting or even totally lake of conditions . If you paste here screenshot of your animator, that would be useful.

[image]

If you want to fix your second problem you should watch this video:

[BRICK SHOOTER - Official Unity Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/assignments/brick-shooter)

Comment: You definitely fixed problem 1 for me. I will look at the video. Thanks